# Redshift with Grafana - ERROR: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error

Tags: amazon-redshift, grafana

I am facing with a query done on Redshift from Grafana where on adding a specific where clause, the above mentioned error is coming. Without this where clause, it is doing fine. Also, if we put a direct value say where first_week > 2, then no error is coming.

where clause:

`WHERE first_week >= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM $__timeFrom AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')`

```
    from  
    (select a.distinct_id, a.login_week, b.first_week as first_week, a.login_week 
    first_week as week_number 
    from (select distinct_id, EXTRACT(WEEK FROM timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS login_week from posthog_event where distinct_id IN ( select distinct_id from activated_user) group by 1, 2) a, 
    select distinct_id, MIN(EXTRACT(WEEK FROM timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')) AS first_week from posthog_event where distinct_id IN ( select distinct_id from activated_user) group by 1) b 
    where a.distinct_id = b.distinct_id
       ) as with_week_number 
       where first_week>= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2022-03-01T17:01:18Z' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
       group by first_week order by first_week
```

Any idea where I am going wrong ? Or what could be done to get the where clause added.

Answer (score 0):

https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-redshift-datasource/

> $__timeFrom() outputs the current starting time of the range of the panel with quotes

=> Grafana macro is `$__timeFrom()` and not only `$__timeFrom`, so correct condition:

```
WHERE first_week >= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM $__timeFrom() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
```

As usual: doc is your good friend

Comment: $__timeFrom works for me with other queries in Grafana but $__timeFrom() doesn't.